# Setting an href on click with a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to make a set of buttons auto-populate with the correct hrefs. The function setLink() is not returning what I expect (which would be something like `localhost:44369/Timeline?d=2020/7/3`). I think that it is because it is not actually using my values m[i],d[i], and y[i], but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```js
var curr = new Date(); // get current date
var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); // First day is set to the  day of the month minus the day of the week
var last = first + 6; // last day is the first day + 6

var day = new Array(7);
day[0] = new Date(curr.setDate(first));
for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
  //This for loop creates the time info for each day with the following loop pulls the month and date out of
  day[i] = new Date(curr.setDate(curr.getDate() + 1));
}

var m = new Array(7);
var d = new Array(7);
var y = new Array(7);
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  //This for loop adds the date
  m[i] = day[i].getMonth() + 1;
  d[i] = day[i].getDate();
  y[i] = day[i].getYear();
  document.getElementById("Timeline-Day" + i).innerHTML += m[i] + "/" + d[i];
  document.getElementById("Timeline-label" + i).onclick = function() {
    setLink();
  };
  function setLink() {
    location.href = '"?d=" y[i] + "/" + m[i] + "/" + d[i]"';
  }
}
```

and my html

```html
 <div style="margin-left:6rem;" id="timelineDiv" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle my-auto col-lg-9" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label onclick="" id="Timeline-label0" class="week btn">
          <span id="Timeline-Day0" class="timeline-label"></span>
          <input type="radio" alt="Sunday" id="option1">
      </label>
      <label id="Timeline-label1" class="week btn">
          <span id="Timeline-Day1" class="timeline-label"></span>
          <input type="radio" name="options" alt="Monday" id="option2">
      </label>
      <label id="Timeline-label2" class="week btn">
          <span id="Timeline-Day2" class="timeline-label"></span>
          <input type="radio" name="options" alt="Tuesday" id="option3">
      </label>
      <label id="Timeline-label3" class="week btn">
          <span id="Timeline-Day3" class="timeline-label"></span>
          <input type="radio" name="options" alt="Wednesday" id="option4">
      </label>
      <label id="Timeline-label4" class="week btn">
          <span id="Timeline-Day4" class="timeline-label"></span>
          <input type="radio" name="options" alt="Thursday" id="option5">
      </label>
      <label id="Timeline-label5" class="week btn">
          <span id="Timeline-Day5" class="timeline-label"></span>
          <input type="radio" name="options" alt="Friday" id="option6">
      </label>
      <label id="Timeline-label6" class="week btn">
          <span id="Timeline-Day6" class="timeline-label"></span>
          <input type="radio" name="options" alt="Saturday" id="option7">
      </label>
</div>
```

Comment: add your html structure too

Comment: This line needs to be fixed 
`location.href = '"?d=" y[i] + "/" + m[i] + "/" + d[i]"';`
to 
location.href = "?d=" + y[i] + "/" + m[i] + "/" + d[i];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setLink` has some funny formatting, you need to use string concatenation (or an alternative) but this below should work

```
  function setLink() {
    location.href = "?d=" + y[i] + "/" + m[i] + "/" + d[i];
  }
```

Additionally, there isn't really much point in using a function for the `onclick` just to call another function you could just do:

```
  document.getElementById("Timeline-label" + i).onclick = function() {
    location.href = '"?d=" y[i] + "/" + m[i] + "/" + d[i]"';
  };
```

Finally, if you changed your `label` to be an `a` element, you could just get it and set the `href` attribute directly, rather than needing to create a function at all

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I changed ```label``` to ```a``` and used ```document.getElementById("Timeline-label" + i).href = "?d=" + y[i] + "/" + m[i] + "/" + d[i];``` It is working but I cant press the ```a```. When I hover over one the correct link appears in the bottom left, but I can't actually click on it.

Comment: If I change back to labels and use ```document.getElementById("Timeline-label" + i).onclick = function () {location.href = "?d=" + y[i] + "/" + m[i] + "/" + d[i];};``` I get localhost:44369/Timeline?d=undefined/undefined/undefined as a url

Comment: When I said set the attribute directly I meant with `.setAttribute('href', yourValue)` which should work

Comment: I changed back to a's and I still can't click on it. It seems like I might have to stick to labels

Comment: It was a scope problem (duh), I just had to change ```i = 0``` to ```let i = 0```

Comment: That's make sense :)